# Access token validation from Google, Google+ Sign-in Android

Tags: android, node.js, validation, google-plus, access-token

I want to fetch an access-token from Google and then send it to my server as a JSON object*.

On server I want to validate the access token and then store essential user information.

My server is written in Node.js. How to do that?

```
 @Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {

    Log.v(TAG, "Connected. Yay!");

    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


    AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String code;
            Bundle appActivities = new Bundle();
            appActivities.putString(GoogleAuthUtil.KEY_REQUEST_VISIBLE_ACTIVITIES,
                    "http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity");
            String scopes = "oauth2:" + Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN + " " + Scopes.PLUS_ME;

            try {
                 code = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(
                        AuthenticationActivity.this,         // Context context
                        mPlusClient.getAccountName(),     // String accountName
                        scopes,                           // String scope
                        appActivities                     // Bundle bundle
                );

            } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
                // Recover
                code = null;
                //System.out.println(e.printStackTrace());
                AuthenticationActivity.this.startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException();

            }
            return code;
       }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String token) {

           /* if(token!=null)
            {
             Log.i(TAG, "Access token retrieved:" + token);
             //SharedPreference = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("TokenPreference", 0); 
             //editor = SharedPreference.edit();
             editor.putString("access_token",token);                               
             editor.commit();                      

            } */

            try
            {
               HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://gumbox1.cloudapp.net:3000");
                JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
                data.put("data", token);
               HttpEntity entity = new StringEntity(data.toString());
               BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.execute(post).getEntity().getContent()));
               String response = reader.readLine();
               Log.e("response", response);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            { Log.e("",e.toString());
            }





        }



      };

    task.execute();
 }
```

Comment: Don't edit question titles to say they are solved. Just mark the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You need to pass auth token to `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=` url. It will return the JSON data for user information.*

---

You should do like

```
private static final String USER_INFO_URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=";

URL url = new URL(USER_INFO_URL + code);
con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
// Now convert into String and then into Json
```

Comment: Ohk so does it validate the token and return the profile stuffs? It means i need not write anything else on server. I will just pass the token to above url and it will validate and return me info. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Yes. If access token is invalid then it returns JSON with the message that will clear that access token was invalid. You can verify this by passing any invalid token with url on any explorer too.

Comment: let say my access token is "k123abc". So i need to pass this way? https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?k123abc=  or "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=" + k123abc ?? Please clarify !

Comment: Last one is correct. See my answer I have added the same.

Comment: I am facing problem while signing in. In some devices i am getting Invalid access token and in some it successfully retrieves profile information. I am not managing the access token manually instead using the PlusClient object that automatically manages the same . Any ideas what may be going in wrong.? Thanks

Comment: @SatyenUdeshi You should check if your google play services is of updated version